# log4j2 Default rollover strategy not deleting logs

Tags: log4j2

I have log4j2 with a default rollover strategy set up like this -

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="cc" filePattern="logs/${baseFileName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="logs/">
                <IfFileName glob="logs/${baseFileName}-*.log" />
                <IfLastModified age="2d" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
```

so it should be deleting the oldest files when it gets to over 2 days old  correct?

my log files are stored in the base path of the project in a folder called logs..

however I just did a test run and it got to 5 files before I stopped it....

any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 5):

Please check the below configuration for deleting old files:
DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" means daily 10 files can be created max.
You can use IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="2" to control how many files will be present at all time. 
 will specify the age of the file, the files older than 2 days from present day will be deleted if the total number of files are grater than 2 (as specified in IfAccumulatedFileCount ).

```
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100">
<Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
  <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log">
    <IfLastModified age="2d">
      <IfAny>
        <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="2" />
      </IfAny>
    </IfLastModified>
  </IfFileName>
</Delete>
```

Maybe it is searching the file to delete in the incorrect path or your log files are not 2 day old.
which version of log4j you are using? it will work for Log4j-2.5 and above

Answer (score 1):

Missing asterisk in the end. Please check -

```
<IfFileName glob="logs/${baseFileName}-*.log*" />
```