# DefaultRolloverStrategy In log4j2

Tags: log4j2, log4j

I am having trouble configuring the "DefaultRolloverStrategy" for log4j2.xml to do the following :-

Ensure ONLY the last 4 log files are kept and older ones should get deleted.
So just be clear, the last 4 log files could be over a number days or on the same day, therefore, 
the last 4 log files could be with the same date or span over different dates.

Below is the contents of log4j2.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <Configuration>

        <Appenders>
            <!-- Console Appender -->
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            </Console>
            <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
            <RollingFile name="File" fileName="app_log.log"
                filePattern="app_log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{DEFAULT} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 KB" />
                </Policies>

                <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                    <Delete basePath="" maxDepth="1">
                        <IfFileName glob="app_log*.txt">
                            <IfAny>
                                <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="5 KB" />
                                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="4" />
                            </IfAny>
                        </IfFileName>
                    </Delete>
                </DefaultRolloverStrategy>

                </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>

        <Loggers>

            <Logger name="com.app.utilities" level="info" additivity="true">
                <AppenderRef ref="File" />
            </Logger>

            <Root level="debug">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            </Root>

        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

I run up my application as shown below

```
java  -Dlog4j.configurationFile=./app-log4j2.xml -jar application.jar
```

The log is generated in the same directory from where the above command is invoked from.

Below is a sample history of log files :-

```
File Name                   Date Modified

app_log.log                 8/27/2018 2:25 PM
app_log-2018-08-27.2.log    8/27/2018 2:25 PM
app_log-2018-08-27.1.log    8/27/2018 2:11 PM
app_log-2018-08-26.5.log    8/26/2018 2:01 PM
app_log-2018-08-26.4.log    8/26/2018 2:00 PM
app_log-2018-08-26.3.log    8/26/2018 1:58 PM
app_log-2018-08-26.2.log    8/26/2018 1:57 PM
app_log-2018-08-26.1.log    8/26/2018 1:56 PM
```

It seems the "DefaultRolloverStrategy" is having no effect.

I presume my configuration is wrong. However, I would very much appreciate for suggestions 
to correct this please.

Also, if the requirenment was to change such that log files greater 20 days should be deleted. 
How could that be acheived.

Thank you very much in advance for you help

Pete

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following line:

```
<IfFileName glob="app_log*.txt">
```

But your log files don't end with `.txt`! See:

```
File Name                   Date Modified

app_log.log                 8/27/2018 2:25 PM
```

You likely need to change it to:

```
<IfFileName glob="app_log*.log">
```

That's what really jumps out to me. There might be another few tweaks you have to make, but try that first.

Comment: Dovmo - good spot thank you.

The other issue seems to be 
<Delete basePath="" maxDepth="1">

The basePath can't be empty so i changed to 
<Delete basePath="." maxDepth="1">

This seems to be working. 

Now  to look at - 

"if the requirenment was to change such that log files greater 20 days should be deleted. How could that be acheived."

Comment: You could do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237731/how-to-delete-old-logs-with-log4j2

Comment: Great 

the following deletes files that are older than 2 days old
 <IfLastModified age="2d"/>

the following will ensure only the last 6 files are kept
 <IfAny>
  <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="6" />
 </IfAny>

attempted to combine the rule as follows :-
        
 <IfLastModified age="2d">
   <IfAny>
  <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="6" />
   </IfAny>
 </IfLastModified>
 
based on this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588333/log4j2-default-rollover-strategy-not-deleting-logs

However, only 2 day rule works but file count doesn't.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: You should probably be asking these questions on a new SO post